# Can I use second fundamental theorem to solve this problem?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

> I have this task of solving
>
> $$g(x)=\int_0^{x^2} y \tan(\pi y)dy$$
>
> and I need to find a $~g'(2)~$.

I was thinking if I could use the second fundamental theorem of calculus, applying it I got this result:
$$g'(x)= y \tan(\pi y)$$
After this I just plug in $x^2$ and $0$
$$g'(x)=x^2\tan(\pi x^2)$$
and got my answer is: $$g'(2)=4\tan(4\pi)$$
Please suggest if this makes any sense and if it doesn't, how else can I solve it?

Comment: You have to multiply by the derivative of $x^2$ which is $2x$. See Liebniz integral rule https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:
If $g(x)=\int_a^{h(x)}f(t)dt$ then $$g'(x)=f(h(x))\frac{d}{dx}h(x)$$
In your case: $$g(x)=\int_0^{h(x)}y\tan(\pi y)\:dy\qquad\text{where }h(x)=x^2$$ Can you go from here$?$

Comment: So do i just $$2x(x^2tan(\pi x^2))$$

Comment: I think i understood, thank you, I got $$16tan(4\pi)$$

Comment: glad to help you. But I am afraid are you understand it correctly. Can you try this, $$g(x)=\int_{h(x)}^{k(x)}f(t)\:dt$$ find $g'(x)$

Comment: I think it should be something like $$g'(x)=f(k(x)) d/dx(k(x)) - f(h(x)) d/dx (h(x))$$ I'm sorry I'm still learning how to type formulas in here   and f(t) will be the d/dx part with the k(x) and h(x) plugged into the f(t)

Comment: Let me give you a hint $$\int_{h(x)}^{k(x)}=\int_{h(x)}^a+\int_a^{k(x)}=-\int_a^{h(x)}+\int_a^{k(x)}$$ You can format in comment box in same way you did in the post. And if my answer help you can mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1):

Given that $$g(x)=\int_0^{x^2} y \tan(\pi y)dy$$
Here $$g'(x)=\int_0^{x^2} \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(y \tan(\pi y)\right)dy+x^2~\tan(
\pi~x^2) \left(\frac{d}{dx}x^2\right)-0 \frac{d0}{dx}$$
$$=2~x^3~\tan(
\pi~x^2)$$

- The above expression is nothing but "Leibniz Integral Rule (Differentiation under the integral sign)".

> **Leibniz Integral Rule (Differentiation under the integral sign):**
>
> Let $f(x, t)$ be a function of $x$ and $t$ such that both $f(x, t)$ and its partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ are continuous in $t$ and $x$ in some region of the $(x, t)$-plane, including $a(x) ≤ t ≤ b(x)$, and $ x_0 ≤ x ≤ x_1$. Also suppose that the functions $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are both continuous and both have continuous derivatives for $x_0 ≤ x ≤ x_1$. Then, for $x_0 ≤ x ≤ x_1$,
> $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t) dt\right)=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} \frac{\partial }{\partial x}f(x,t) dt +f( x, b(x)) \frac{db}{dx}-f( x, a(x)) \frac{da}{dx}$$

- The (first) fundamental theorem of calculus is just the particular case of the above formula where $~a(x) = a~$, a constant, $~b(x) = x~$, and $~f(x, t) = f(t)~$.